# Get values from unserialized data

Tags: php, arrays

I have a serialized field in my database. I can get the contents of this field and unserialize them however I am unsure how to get certain values of these. I ultimately need a foreach of each item and value from the data.

In the below example I need to be able to get the following:

> Main Image Replacement:
>   BGL_Burhill_People_AndyHiseman_300dpi_Super-Size-14.JPG Complimentary:
>   Comp Text Quote Code: Code Text

I need the label as one variable and the value as another within a foreach. These labels and values are variable so I cannot manually get this data by their labels.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'mode' => 'builder',
    'cssclass' => '',
    'hidelabelinorder' => '',
    'hidevalueinorder' => '',
    'element' => 
    array (
      'type' => 'radio',
      'rules_type' => 
      array (
        'Reprint_0' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'Edit Artwork_1' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
      ),
      '_' => 
      array (
        'price_type' => '',
      ),
    ),
    'name' => '',
    'value' => 'Edit Artwork',
    'price' => '',
    'section' => '58073632e582b5.35893028',
    'section_label' => '',
    'percentcurrenttotal' => 0,
    'currencies' => 
    array (
    ),
    'price_per_currency' => 
    array (
      'GBP' => '',
    ),
    'quantity' => 1,
    'multiple' => '1',
    'key' => 'Edit Artwork_1',
    'use_images' => '',
    'changes_product_image' => '',
    'imagesp' => '',
    'images' => '',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'mode' => 'builder',
    'cssclass' => '',
    'hidelabelinorder' => '',
    'hidevalueinorder' => '',
    'element' => 
    array (
      'type' => 'radio',
      'rules_type' => 
      array (
        'BGL_Burhill_People_AndyHiseman_300dpi_Super-Size-14.JPG_0' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'BGL_Burhill_People_AndyHiseman_300dpi_Super-Size-21.JPG_1' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'BGL_Burhill_People_AndyHiseman_300dpi_Super-Size-77.JPG_2' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
      ),
      '_' => 
      array (
        'price_type' => '',
      ),
    ),
    'name' => 'Main Image Replacement',
    'value' => 'BGL_Burhill_People_AndyHiseman_300dpi_Super-Size-14.JPG',
    'price' => '',
    'section' => '58073632e582d2.46631826',
    'section_label' => 'Main Image Replacement',
    'percentcurrenttotal' => 0,
    'currencies' => 
    array (
    ),
    'price_per_currency' => 
    array (
      'GBP' => '',
    ),
    'quantity' => 1,
    'multiple' => '1',
    'key' => 'BGL_Burhill_People_AndyHiseman_300dpi_Super-Size-14.JPG_0',
    'use_images' => 'images',
    'changes_product_image' => '',
    'imagesp' => '',
    'images' => 'http://burhill.immaculate.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/BGL_Burhill_People_AndyHiseman_300dpi_Super-Size-14-150x150.jpg',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'mode' => 'builder',
    'cssclass' => 'col-6',
    'hidelabelinorder' => '',
    'hidevalueinorder' => '',
    'element' => 
    array (
      'type' => 'textfield',
      'rules_type' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
      ),
      '_' => 
      array (
        'price_type' => '',
      ),
    ),
    'name' => 'Complimentary',
    'value' => 'Comp Text',
    'price' => '',
    'section' => '58073632e582f4.32183997',
    'section_label' => 'Complimentary',
    'percentcurrenttotal' => 0,
    'currencies' => 
    array (
    ),
    'price_per_currency' => 
    array (
    ),
    'quantity' => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'mode' => 'builder',
    'cssclass' => 'col-6',
    'hidelabelinorder' => '',
    'hidevalueinorder' => '',
    'element' => 
    array (
      'type' => 'textfield',
      'rules_type' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
      ),
      '_' => 
      array (
        'price_type' => '',
      ),
    ),
    'name' => 'Quote Code',
    'value' => 'Code Text',
    'price' => '',
    'section' => '58073632e58317.46363272',
    'section_label' => 'Quote Code',
    'percentcurrenttotal' => 0,
    'currencies' => 
    array (
    ),
    'price_per_currency' => 
    array (
    ),
    'quantity' => 1,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. And your array looks messy and seem to have no systematic arrangements. Make it readable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, as the array contains variable data, there's no other way around it other than looping through all the data until you find whatever it is that you're looking for. You haven't posted any code so it's unclear what have you tried or what problems or errors are you facing. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($your_array as $key => $value) {
  $your_value = $value['value'];
  $your_label = $value['section_label'];
}
```

This should work for you as long as i got the right keys there.